# Is there a way to tell programmatically if a PayPal Client ID and Secret is from a Sandbox or Live environment?

Tags: paypal

When you create a new App on PayPal, there are 2 environments, sandbox and live. Each environment provides a Client ID and Secret, they are different for each environment, but is there a way to tell from a programmatic point of view if the Client ID/Secret belongs to a sandbox environment or a live environment?

Using Stripe, their keys are prefixed clearly with either 'live' or 'test' and it makes it easy to validate and know visibly which one is which, whereas PayPals are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no.

You can't tell them apart w/o knowing where they were copied from, or testing them against live/sandbox endpoints.

Edit: one way to test them against live vs. sandbox endpoints would be to request an oauth token ( https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token )

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming this. Is it possible to run the credentials through some part of the API to check it doesn't return a personal.example.com or business.example.com sandbox email or environment?

Comment: Not that I know of---but the two environments are completely separate, so credentials can only work in exactly one environment, never in another. Any call in the other environment will return a failure.

Comment: That's what I thought, but we have a strange setup on a client site, selected users can distribute products on the companies behalf, we ask for their Client ID and Secret, encrypt and store it, then at the checkout we decrypt them and append it to the JS SDK url, which means, if that user has given us Sandbox credentials by mistake, the customer will buy in a Sandbox environment which will of course cause problems. I was just hoping there was a way we could run the ID/Secret through the API before we encrypt it to validate they are live so we know every order will be live.

Comment: Well if you have an ID/secret  (not just an ID), the you can do an API call to e.g obtain an oauth token.  A live ID/secret will work when connecting to api.paypal.com , whereas a sandbox ID/secret will fail in that connection (the latter can only work when connecting to api.sandbox.paypal.com)

Comment: If you supply a sandbox Client ID to the JS SDK (https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js), the button provided by that, when clicked, will just load sandbox.paypal.com, whereas a live Client ID would load paypal.com. There isn't a point where you can explicitly declare what environment should load. I'll update the original question shortly with a better explanation of the whole setup.

Comment: You mentioned wanting to run the ID/Secret through the API. See my latest comment above for that.

Comment: Verifying the credentials by obtaining an oauth token does the trick! I can do this at the point the user provides us with their Client ID and Secret in their account and look for an access token against the api.paypal.com request then I know they gave us the correct credentials and not sandbox credentials. Thanks for your help, if you could edit your answer with a link to the access token docs (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token) I'll mark this as correct, appreciate your patience :)